# Error while doing heroku push

Tags: git, heroku, git-push

I have two apps(say A and B) in heroku account. I pushed code of 'A'app into the other heroku app 'B' by mistake. Then i just did rollback for 'B' app.

Now when am trying to push changes into heroku app 'B' project.

it throws following error.

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to  'LINK TO HEROKU APP'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
```

WHat to do now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git push heroku master -f
```

I had remove all the files which are not related to 'A' Project manually.

Answer (score 1):

If you're absolutely sure that you simply want to push changes from app B to heroku, then you can add the `-f` flag to force push.

## WARNING

be careful because this will automatically override whatever was previously on your master branch with what you are pushing.

It would look like:

```
git push heroku master -f
```

Comment: So this will delete all those code of 'A' App and make the changes.right?

Comment: Yeah, it will remove everything currently on heroku master (which is A I believe) with B

Comment: will this also delete those files which are added when i pushed 'A' code. I want all those files to get deleted.

Comment: yes it should remove the files from A from heroku master

Comment: git push heroku master -f this is also failing